# Angular Reactive form asynchronous operation

Tags: asynchronous, angular-reactive-forms, change-password

I am getting this error when I try to build a reactive form for creating a new password form.I have mentioned the source code  below and when I remove the source code part then there is no error but without that my operation is not working as well. I think I have to add or delete something in my source code to get the desired output

```
main.ts:12 TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at FormGroup.passwordShouldMatch [as validator] (password.validators.ts:18)
    at FormGroup._runValidator (forms.js:4089)
    at FormGroup.updateValueAndValidity (forms.js:4050)
    at new FormGroup (forms.js:4927)
    at FormBuilder.group (forms.js:8924)
    at new ChangePasswordComponent (change-password.component.ts:15)
    at createClass (core.js:31987)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:31807)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:44210)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44660)






  static passwordShouldMatch(control : AbstractControl) {
        let newPassword = control.get('newPassowrd');
        let confirmPassword = control.get('confirmPassowrd');

        if (newPassword.value !== confirmPassword.value){
            return { passwordShouldMatch:true };

                return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Share complete code snippet of the component file along with the template. If possible create a minimal reproducible app in Stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't add any code snippet I am considering your form structure is something like this.

```
this.fb.group({
  newPassowrd: [''],
  confirmPassowrd: [''],
});
```

here, you include an custom validation function called passwordShouldMatch and this function looks fine. So, I assume that you did something wrong when you set the validator to that form group.

```
this.fb.group({
  newPassowrd: [''],
  confirmPassowrd: [''],
}, { validator: this.passwordShouldMatch});
```

this is how you should set the validation function for the form group. And in html your form should be something like this.

```
<form [formGroup]="form" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(survey)">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Untitled form" formControlName="newPassowrd">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Untitled form" formControlName="confirmPassowrd">
    <span *ngIf="form.hasError('passwordShouldMatch')">not match</span>
</form>
```

everything should work this way. Here is the working version of [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/formbuilder-zaxsrd)

Comment: Actually I misspell password that was the reason. anyhow thanks for supporting me

Comment: you are welcome.. glad to hear that you found and solved you issue. but as I invested some time here and if the content of my answer helps you in any way, feel free to do a vote.